# How to use https proxies with fetch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy

I'm attempting to send a post request with a http proxy via fetch and haven't found any posts about how to do so. Here's what I have as of now:

```js
fetch("https:/Apienpoint.com", {
    "method" : "POST",
    "credentials" : "same-origin",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Referer" : "https://www.example.com",
      "Origin" : "https://www.example.com",
      "User-Agent" : "Useragent",
    },
    "body" : JSON.stringify({
      "Item" : "Value"
    })
  },
  {'http':'http://ProxiesIpAdress:ProxiesPort'},
).then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.headers);
  });
```

I'm sure this isn't correct and need help finding the correct way to do this.
And just for extra info I'm using vanilla js on the client side.

If your wondering why I need the request sent with proxies I have to redeem a token with the api on the same ip it was created. So if I use a proxy on both events of being created and redeemed it  should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know, you can not use Proxies config with native `fetch()` . You can try `node-fetch` or `axios` instead.

Comment: I may have not made this clear but im not using node-js im using browser js so using those are out of the question. Thanks for the help though!